# checking multiple input arguments

Tags: c#, .net

What is a good way to check multiple input parameters to a function and throw an exception containing information for all the invalid ones. I do not want to have multiple if/case conditions. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName, string password)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    string theMessage = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId))
    {
        log.Error(Message);
        return error response;
    } 

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecret))
    {        
        log.Error(Message);
        return error response;
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no - after all at some point you have to actually check each of the individual values for validity, and only you know what that validity entails.

A longer answer is that it would be possible to use objects that themselves know whether or not they are valid, but you would still have to ask the object to validate itself e.g. clientSecret.IsValid would return a boolean that you could compare.

Following this pattern you could use Linq to automatically check a list or other IEnumerable of objects (for example making sure that they all inherit from an interface you might create called something like IValidatable) using the Any clause e.g.

```
if (validatableList.Any(x => x.IsValid)
{
    // Throw exception here
}
```

You could also reverse it and use the All clause to confirm that all objects pass the validation rather than that none fail it.

However, this does mean not using any object that is not capable of self-validating and it also means that you do not get detailed error messages relating to the issue that caused the failure.  You could address that by adding an Errors property that retrieves a set of errors that arise from the validation, but again you are simply moving the work elsewhere.

Another option would be to use a configuration object as the parameter to the method and build your validation routines into that:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(MessageConfig config)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        string theMessage = null;

        if (!config.IsValid)
        {
           log.Error(Message);
           return error response;
        } 

           ...........
    }
```

You could also build a Rules engine and pass the various values to that for validation, e.g. a rule could be defined something like this:

```
        // Must have a name
        var e = new Expression();
        e.Add(new IsNotNullOrEmpty<string>(GetName));
        Validator.AddRule(new RuleSet(e, null, ShowMissingNameError,
            FailureBehaviour.Terminate, ValidationLevel.Fatal));
```

This though only makes sense for complicated objects in an inheritance hierarchy that all need to know whether or not they are valid, and you would have to apply a known set of rules to each one as you code them.  Yet it makes consuming that validation trivial on your outer code e.g.:

```
if (!myObject.IsValid)
{
    log.Error(myObject.Errors)
}
```

At some point, however you decide to do it, the objects will have to be validated individually to see if they meet the rules you have set to confirm validity and these rules will be different depending on the type and the usage.  For example, an int can never be null, but it might need validating to confirm that it is not less than zero.

So, in summary, whilst you can abstract the work away to a different part of your code if you wish you cannot get rid of that work entirely.

I hope that this is helpful.

Comment: Good explanation and thank you!!